# How to send the logs in batches from Log4j2 HTTPAppender

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2, mulesoft

We have got a scenario where logs from MuleSoft need to be sent to Datadog which has been achieved but the log4j2 HTTPAppender needs to be configured in such a way that logs may travel to Datadog in batches. For Example: when 10 MBs of logs have been collected each time then send the logs to an external system (Datadog).

Is there a way that we can achieve it through log4j2 HTTPAppender?

Answer (score 0):

This question is purely related to Log4j2's HTTPAppender behavior. According to the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) there is no way to buffer by log size before sending the log entries to an HTTP request. You would need to implement your own custom appender to achieve that.

Note that keeping 10 MB of logs in memory may have a counterproductive impact on resource usage. You'll need to test the behavior in real life to see if that's acceptable.

You can find some information on creating a custom appender on:

- https://www.baeldung.com/log4j2-custom-appender
- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html

Comment: Hi @aled 
Thanks for your quick response. Actually, the logs will be pretty less than 10 MB, just for the example, I mentioned 10MB. However, would you suggest or refer to some documentation to create the custom appender? Also, will it be a better approach that we're going to collect logs and send over HTTP altogether instead of the default Async Logger?

Comment: Added custom appender links to the answer. You should use Async loggers always, unless you have a very good reason and understanding of how Log4j2 async logging works. That's independent of the HTTP appender. I can not comment on what is a better approach as I'm lacking context for your requirements, resources, policies, etc, and it would be outside of the scope of a Stackoverflow question/answer. I have merely pointed to a potential issue with this approach so you are aware of that.

Comment: @aled what is the behavior of Log4j httpAppender which is available by default (not the custom one). Will it make a separate http call for each log4j statement ? and this can have performance issues for the application if there are too many log statements

Comment: Documentation indicates that it uses Java HttpUrlConnection as its implementation of HTTP requests but it doesn't clarify if the appender tries to disconnect or preserves the connection.

Comment: How does log4j work.. whenever there is a log statement, log4j picks and puts it to a queue and custom appender will then pick it from the queue and send it to out file or http endpoint ... Is this understanding correct ?

Comment: This discussion largely exceeds the scope of the original question. Best practice in Stack overflow is that comments should be used to clarify the answer, not to answer questions. Please open new question or questions.